how to change Change ByVal Target As Range in google sheets
How can I change cell after selecting on dropdown in google sheets?
I have a VB code but I can't convert it to App Script
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then
Target.Offset(1, -1).Select
End If
End Sub

Can you please help me on this, Thanks a lot!

I would like to confirm if what this script does is when you edit a cell on column 1, then the cell on column 2 will be selected and vice versa?

Please let me know if the answer I posted below works.

Use onEdit(e)
The VB script you are currently using will just select the cell on column B if you are editing something in column A and vice versa. In Google Apps Script, your VB script should somehow look like this:
function onEdit(e) { //triggers the script when you edit any cell on the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //gets the active sheet you are currently editing
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); //gets the column number of the cell you are currently editing
  var row = e.range.getRow(); //gets the column of the cell you are currently editing

  if (col == 1) {
    ss.getRange(row, col + 1).activate(); //selects the cell on column 2
  }
  else if (col == 2) {
    ss.getRange(row, col - 1).activate(); //selects the cell on column 1
  }
}

You only need to save this script and it will automatically run when you are doing some edits on column A OR column B. The result should be like this:

Reference:

Simple Triggers


Please feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.
